# Nhibernate SQLQuery as Subquery

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

How Can use a native sqlquery (session.CreateSqlQuery) as filtering subquery in another QueryOver:

```
                // Get  ids
            var idsq = _session.CreateSQLQuery(
                "select Id from [dbo].[SomeFunction](:parameter)")
                .AddEntity(typeof(long)).
                SetParameter("parameter", folderId);

            // get entities by filtering where in (subquery)
            MyEntity entityAlias = null;
            var listOfEntities = await _session.QueryOver(() => entityAlias).
                Where(x=>x.Id).IsIn(idsq).
                OrderBy(x => x.Name).Asc.
                ListAsync(cancelToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: I don't think you can do it like this - you'd have to return the result of `idsq` to the client, which is probably a bad idea as you don't know how large it is. You can probably add `[dbo].[SomeFunction]` to a custom sql dialect and use it that way - see http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/03/13/registering-freetext-or-contains-functions-into-a-nhibernate-dialect.html or https://ayende.com/blog/1720/using-sql-functions-in-nhibernate

Comment: I don't think you can easily do it... The "direction" should be: `.WithSubquery.WhereProperty(x => x.Id).In(...)` but then the `In` requires a `QueryOver` query.

Comment: I dont' know why NH cant handle this case, because it should be easy to embed native SQL inside a where in () in generated sql or even join to table valued sql function

Comment: Also see http://www.andrewwhitaker.com/blog/2014/08/15/queryover-series-part-7-using-sql-functions/ which suggests using `Projections.SqlFunction`

Comment: @DavidKemp Thanks, My problem solved by Accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't easily mix various styles of NHibernate... What you can do:

```
var crit = new SQLCriterion(SqlString.Parse("{alias}.Id IN (select Id from [dbo].[SomeFunction](?))"),
                                    new object[] { folderId },
                                    new IType[] { NHibernateUtil.Int64 });
```

and then:

```
var listOfEntities = await _session.QueryOver(() => entityAlias)
    .Where(crit)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Name).Asc
```

Note how I changed the text query adding `{alias}.Id IN (...)`

Comment: Thanks So Much, It worked perfectly, I think this is a must to have trick for legacy database

Comment: NHibernate use function in another one to many query for a One-To-Many association between  MyEntity  and another child collection table, Do you have any suggestion to make it one time call without producing Cartesian production result

Comment: @HamidNaeemi Unclear what you are asking... and it seems to be quite complex... you should make another question.